# Play a chord when a specific number is typed

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, collections

I'm trying to play a chord when a specific number is typed.

For example, if you type "1", the function will play the chord "Amaj", if you type "2", the function will play the sound "Amin".

I have 48 sound files stored in the same directory as my Excel Workbook.

I've been trying to use a collection.

```
Private Declare Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
  Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, _
  ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
```

```
Sub ChordDictionary()

    Dim ChordDict As Collection
    Set ChordDict = New Collection
    ChordDict.Add 1, "Amaj.wav"
    ChordDict.Add 2, "Amin.wav"
    ChordDict.Add 3, "Aaug.wav"
    ChordDict.Add 4, "Adim.wav"
    ChordDict.Add 5, "A#maj.wav"
    ChordDict.Add 6, "A#min.wav"
    ChordDict.Add 7, "A#aug.wav"
    ChordDict.Add 8, "A#dim.wav"
    ChordDict.Add 9, "Bmaj.wav"
    etc...
End Sub
```

```
Function Sound(Cell)
    
    Dim WAVFile As String
    Const SND_ASYNC = &H1
    Const SND_FILENAME = &H200000
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ChordDict.Count
        If i = Cell Then
            SoundFile = ChordDict(i)
            WAVFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & SoundFile & "\"
            Call PlaySound(WAVFile, 0&, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)
            Alarm = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
        
ErrHandler:
    SoundAlert = False

End Function
```

My function does not output any value.

Comment: Where exactly are you typing this specific number?

Comment: First tip: add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and declare all your variables.

Comment: What Excel version do you use? Is it 32 bit, or VBA less then 7?

Comment: Where, in your code, do you call the function in discussion? `ChordDict` must be declared of the module level. Otherwise, it is valid only in the procedure where it has been declared...

Comment: Please, test my answer code and let me know if it works as you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Unfortunately, when I tried to run the code, the debugger stated  "Compile Error: Variable not defined" and highlighted the "Function Sound (Cell As Long)" line. Any clue what may be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a workable code, please proceed in the next way:

Add this code on top of your module (declarations area). `PlaySound` function for 64 bit looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function PlaySound Lib "winmm.dll" _
                Alias "PlaySoundA" (ByVal lpszName As String, _
                 ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Private ChordDict As New Collection
```

Then in a module, place the next code:

```
Sub ChordDictionary()
    Set ChordDict = Nothing
    ChordDict.aDD "Amaj.wav", "1"
    ChordDict.aDD "Amin.wav", "2"
    ChordDict.aDD "Aaug.wav", "3"
    ChordDict.aDD "Adim.wav", "4"
    ChordDict.aDD "A#maj.wav", "5"
    ChordDict.aDD "A#min.wav", "6"
    ChordDict.aDD "A#aug.wav", "7"
    ChordDict.aDD "A#dim.wav", "8"
    ChordDict.aDD "Bmaj.wav", "9"

    Sound 3 'you call here the function, for the third collection element
End Sub
```

And the function to play the wave file:

```
Function Sound(Cell As Long)
    Dim WAVFile As String, SoundFile As String
    Const SND_ASYNC = &H1
    Const SND_FILENAME = &H200000

    For i = 1 To ChordDict.count
        If i = Cell Then
            SoundFile = ChordDict(i)
            WAVFile = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & SoundFile
            Call PlaySound(WAVFile, 0&, SND_ASYNC Or SND_FILENAME)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

You must run the `Sub ChordDictionary` and set, in its last code line, the collection element to be played.

I suppose it is clear for you that all wave files having the name in collection **must exist in the folder where the workbook keeping this code exists**...

After loading the collection, you can call the `Sound` function from any other `Sub`.

Comment: `Set ChordDict = Nothing` - don't you need to be creating the object there?

Comment: @Tim Williams: Only if the collection has not been loaded before. It, practically, clean the collection and the following code loads the elements... `ChordDict` has been declared at the module level.

Comment: ..of course - forgot about the whole `As New` auto-instancing...